# Convert POJO to json in a conroller

Tags: grails

I've managed to convert POGO to json via

```
class Test {
        String test
}
def local = new Test()
local.test = "1234"
render test as JSON
```

However when trying to convert a java class (declared in a different library) I'm always getting back the class type

```
public class RegistrationDetails {
    /**
     * The registration token used to identify the device from now on.
     */
    public String registrationToken;
}

RegistrationDetails details = new RegistrationDetails()
details.registrationToken="123"
render details as JSON
```

instead of getting

```
{
 "registrationToken":"123"
}
```

Instead I'm getting back

```
{
    "class": "data.com.shared.RegistrationDetails"
}
```

Am I missing something ?

Comment: It's not clear from your question. Are you only getting back the class or are you asking how to exclude the class?

Comment: Include the code for the `RegistrationDetails` class with your question. That will assist in finding the answer.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore included

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting an object to JSON is based on properties. `String test` in a Groovy class defines a property named "test" because it's a field with no scope modifier. It defaults to public, and the Groovy compiler converts `String test` to a private field and a getter and a setter. If you decompile `Test` (e.g. with [jd-gui](http://jd.benow.ca/) or another decompiler) you'll see something similar to this (with a bunch of other code that's not relevant here):

```
public class Test implements GroovyObject {

   private String test;

   ...

   public String getTest() {
      return test;
   }

   public void setTest(String paramString) {
      test = paramString;
   }
}
```

It won't replace an existing getter or setter, so you're free to customize either or both if you need custom logic when getting and/or setting. If you explicitly make the field public (`public String test`) or use any other scope modifier then this conversion doesn't occur.

This is how domain classes work; Hibernate doesn't have any support for Groovy but it doesn't need any - it sees the getters and setters like it would if you had created a typical verbose POJO. It's also how Spring bean dependency injection works; if you have a field in a controller/service/taglib/etc. like `def sessionFactory` or `SessionFactory sessionFactory`, Groovy adds a getter and setter, and Spring sees the setter and since Grails uses autowiring by name, if there's a bean named "sessionFactory" Spring will call your setter and inject it.

Your Java class doesn't have a property - it has a public field, and the Java compiler doesn't do anything special with it, and neither Groovy nor Grails do anything with it either since it's a Java class. So the only data that's available from the class via a getter is the class since every class has a `getClass` method.

The JSON conversion excludes the `class` "property" in Groovy classes but not Java but that appears to be a bug; the loop in [GenericJavaBeanMarshaller](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-plugin-converters/src/main/groovy/org/grails/web/converters/marshaller/json/GenericJavaBeanMarshaller.java#L47) (the helper class for POJOs) only excludes `PropertyDescriptor`s that have no getter, but the loop in [GroovyBeanMarshaller](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-plugin-converters/src/main/groovy/org/grails/web/converters/marshaller/json/GroovyBeanMarshaller.java#L62) excludes the `getMetaClass` and `getClass` getters.

Comment: tx by adding get to the POJO fixed the problem. The bug that you mentioned is it a known bug ?

Comment: I don't know if it's been reported, but I tend to avoid bulk `render foo as JSON` calls and either build a map/list with the data that I know I want to send, or use `JSON.registerObjectMarshaller()` to define how to convert individual classes.

Comment: But what if I have multiple classes that I share between my client (Android) and the server, it's really convenient to use the general "as JSON" functionality. What is the suggested pattern here ?

Comment: It comes down to what data is in the class and what you want to send for various remote calls. I rarely want every property rendered for every call except for simple data classes. Sending lots of unnecessary data will make calls sluggish and affect scalability if the classes are large. I also like that the code is more self-documenting since it's obvious what's being sent; `render foo as JSON` is opaque and requires that you look at `foo` to know what's happening.